# Liquibase development stage

Tags: maven, liquibase

I am new to liquibase. I read the manual and some tutorials. And I want to use it in our current project. Just want to ask question about development stage. And we will be using maven plugin.

Suppose to be I put a changeset which is add column in an existing table, and the other developer also add column in that table. Do we just need to use the same changeset? and how can I reflect his changes to my local database and how can he that also?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each change should be one changeset. Most probably (depends on how you organize your changelog files) they will both be within the same changelog file.

Normally you would add your changeset to the "current" changelog file and check it in to some source code repository. Your other developer checks it out and runs that changelog file with his/her local db. Same applies of course to you when someone else changes something in the db and adds another changeset.